# Can't invoke action on the button inside ng-repeat directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, and while playing with it, i have encountered with the problem.... I have a table like this :

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="line in lines">
<remove-line>
            <input id="line_id" type="hidden" value="{{line.id}}">
            <td id="sn">{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{line.ref}}</td>
            <td>{{line.label}}</td>
            <td class="tva">{{line.tva}}</td>
            <td class="qty">{{line.qty}}</td>
            <td class="unity">{{line.unity}}</td>
            <td class="prix">{{line.prix}}</td>
            <td>{{line.prix*line.qty}}</td>

            <td><button class="btn" id= "remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i> </button></td>
         </remove-line>
        </tr>
...
```

I want to have some behavior when clicking on the remove button, using custom directive. AngularJS code looks like :

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('removeLine',function(){
    var remove = function(){
    ...
        alert ("Oops removed!");
    }

    return {
           restrict: 'E',
           link : function(scope,element, attrs){
               $("#remove").on('click', remove);

           }


    };
});
```

But this doesn't work.... Nothing happens when i click on the remove button in the table..... But all this work fine when the button is out of the  tag. Why is it so and how make it work?

I have created jsfiddle to illustrate my situation http://jsfiddle.net/alexrussinov/cs8RP/71/. What is strange that when I test this code on my local machine buttons in the table don't work but two separate under it, work fine. On jsfiddle, neither in the table nor below it, it doesn't work.

Comment: start by using valid html structure..  can't place arbitrary elements as child of `<tr>`. `input` and `<remove-line>` aren't valid

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple elements on a page with the same ID, which is what you're doing with the button.

I think the simplest solution would be to stick the `remove()` call directly in the button tag with `ng-click`, passing in the line that you wish to remove. This of course assumes that your `remove()` method is part of `$scope`.

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="remove(line)"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
```

Comment: +1 for the best practice `ngClick` recommendation. Directives aren't places to shove jQuery, free of rules. AngularJS best practices still apply inside directives, people! :-)

Comment: Yes, with multiple elements with the same ID I got excited. I have removed IDs and now I try to reference my button by class name like this:`<button class="btn remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>` and angularjs code : `... return {restrict: 'E',
link : function(scope,element, attrs){ $(".remove").on('click', remove);  .....}`but it also doesn't work. I know how to do that with ng-click and my controller like @jszobody propose but I want to understand why jquery `on.('click',...)` doesn't work inside ng-repeat directive and implement all this with custom directive.So why and how ?

Comment: I think that when you attach events with jquery you are loosing angularjs scope, and then can't call the method inside the directive. This isn't how angularjs is meant to be used. Use controllers for your logic. Ngclick for binding the event. Why build an angularjs app and then fight with how it is designed?

Comment: It's not scope loosing problem. For example : http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/E7xER/ The author uses jquery for listening click events on <div> and it works perfect. I want the same behaviour but on my buttons which are inside ng-repeat directive, and that what doesn't work for me.And of course this is not a fight with how angular is designed...

Comment: That fiddle is accessing the div with angular.element, not a raw jquery  selector. If you put together a jsfiddle of your situation and update your question I'd be happy to take a look. It would also help for you to explain why you don't want to use the proper ngclick handler, so that we understand better.

Comment: How we get access to the div element in that example doesn't matter,I can change the code to use jquery selector and it will work fine http://jsfiddle.net/alexrussinov/Xh9f6/, but I have edited the question with a link for my situation.